# ¿Por qué la función no me retorna el resultado correcto en jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, funciones, botón, click

¡Hola! Hice una función con el proposito de que pase un valor de temperatura en Fahrenheit a otras unidades como Celsius, Kelvin, etc. Por desgracia, al vincular la función con la función del evento click, parece que el resultado me da incorrecto incluso al elegir otras unidades de conversión mediante un combo desplegable. ¿Por qué ocurre eso?

```
$("#btnConvertir").click(mostrarConversion);
function mostrarConversion(){
    fahrenheit = Number($("#txtFahrenheit").val());
    temperatura = $("#slcTemp").val();
    let resultado = console.log(determinarTemperatura(fahrenheit, temperatura)); // retorno 
}

let temp;

function determinarTemperatura(valorFahrenheit, unidadTemp){
    if(unidadTemp === "C"){
        temp = ((valorFahrenheit - 32) / 1.8).toFixed(3);

    }else if(unidadTemp === "K"){
        temp = ((valorFahrenheit + 459.67) / 1.8).toFixed(3);

    }else if(unidadTemp === "R"){
        temp = valorFahrenheit + 459.67;

    }else{
        temp = ((valorFahrenheit - 32) / 2.25).toFixed(3);

    }
    return temp;
}
/* determinarTemperatura(20, "C");
determinarTemperatura(20, "K");
determinarTemperatura(20, "R");
determinarTemperatura(20, "Reaumur") */
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <label for="txtFahrenheit">Temperatura (°F):</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtFahrenheit">
    <select id="slcTemp">
        <option val="C">Celsius</option>
        <option val="K">Kelvin</option>
        <option val="R">Rankine</option>
        <option val="RE">Réaumur</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Convertir" id="btnConvertir">
    <p id="pResultado"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica en tu HTML, el atributo de `<option>` se llama `value=` y no `val=`

Como no había un `value` JQuery tomada el del texto en este caso `Celsius` en lugar de `C` y por lo tanto siempre entraba en el `else`

Cambiando todos los `val` por `value` en los `option` debería funcionar como en el script

```js
$("#btnConvertir").click(mostrarConversion);
function mostrarConversion(){
    fahrenheit = Number($("#txtFahrenheit").val());
    temperatura = $("#slcTemp").val();
    console.log(temperatura)
    let resultado = console.log(determinarTemperatura(fahrenheit, temperatura)); // retorno 
}

let temp;

function determinarTemperatura(valorFahrenheit, unidadTemp){

    if(unidadTemp === "C"){
        temp = ((valorFahrenheit - 32) / 1.8).toFixed(3);

    }else if(unidadTemp === "K"){
        temp = ((valorFahrenheit + 459.67) / 1.8).toFixed(3);

    }else if(unidadTemp === "R"){
        temp = valorFahrenheit + 459.67;

    }else{
        temp = ((valorFahrenheit - 32) / 2.25).toFixed(3);

    }
    return temp;
}
/* determinarTemperatura(20, "C");
determinarTemperatura(20, "K");
determinarTemperatura(20, "R");
determinarTemperatura(20, "Reaumur") */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="txtFahrenheit">Temperatura (°F):</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtFahrenheit">
    <select id="slcTemp">
        <option value="C">Celsius</option>
        <option value="K">Kelvin</option>
        <option value="R">Rankine</option>
        <option value="RE">Réaumur</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Convertir" id="btnConvertir">
    <p id="pResultado"></p>
```

Comment: Es muy cierto. ¡Muchísimas gracias!